# The two-sided half-open interval topology on $\mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology

I'm having a bit of trouble coming to terms with the basics of topology. I'm pretty sure this proof is wrong - can it be fixed?

Exercise. Let $T$ be the topology on $\mathbb R$ with the set of all intervals $(x,y]$ and $[x,y)$ as a subbasis. Show that $T=\mathscr P(\mathbb R)$ ($T$ is discrete).

Proof?. First note that any one-point set $\{x\}$ can be written $\{x\}=(a,x]\cap[x,b)$ for $a<x<b$. Then for any $U\subset\mathbb R$ we write $U=\bigcup_{x\in U}\{x\}$ so that $U$ is a union of finite intersections of such intervals as desired.$\quad\square$

The biggest concern I have with this argument is that it also shows the topology generated by intervals $[x,y]$ is discrete. Is this also the case, and if not where does this argument fail?

Comment: We speak of a topology as generated by open sets, not closed sets.  The usual topology on $\Bbb R$ is generated by intervals $(x,y)$  When you close the intervals you add more open sets, so it is not surprising you have a different (finer) topology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument seems completely correct to me, and yes, using the same argument the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ generated by the intervals $[x,y]$ is the discrete topology. Even easier:
$$[x,x]=\{x\}$$

Comment: If you don't insist on making it even easier, the OP's argument shows that the intervals $[x,y]$ with $x\lt y$ generate the discrete topology.